# SQLite : Update not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite

refer below posts but can't help for me

- [SQLiteDatabase update not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532859/sqlitedatabase-update-not-working?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [Android sqlite UPDATE not works properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625611/android-sqlite-update-not-works-properly)
- [Android SQLite Update not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575211/android-sqlite-update-not-working)

Problem is i'll change data and click on Save Button it's can't update my data

when i print my **`ID`** then it's say **`NULL`**

**Update Query** :

```
db.update(COMPANY, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(company.getId()) });
```

**Java code:**

```
else{
    count = 0;

Company company = new Company();                                   
company.setName(etCompanyName.getText().toString().trim())                            
company.setWebsite(etWebsite.getText().toString().trim());
company.setEmail(etEmail.getText().toString().trim());                                
company.setPhoneHome(etPhoneHome.getText().toString().trim());                                    
company.setPhonePrimary(etPhonePrimary.getText().toString().trim());                                
company.setAddressLine1(etAddressLine1.getText().toString().trim());                                    

 long isUpdated = myDb.updateCompany(company);

 //Show id hear But it's null
 Log.e("TAG", "Id : " + company.getId());

 if (isUpdated != -1) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Company Update Successfully: " + isUpdated, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     Log.e("Button..."," Update Button Clickd ");
     finish();
}
```

When i click on Save Button it's print Toast msg : 
***Company Update Successfully 0*** every time

Comment: I don't see in your code where you set the id. Where is the line `company.setId`?

Comment: i can't set id i was just Use LOG to see id for conformation data update or not but id is null @RubioRic

Comment: I don't understand you, your update query requires an id. If you don't establish one, no row will be updated

Comment: simply i click on Save button data can't update and show toast msg : `Company Update Successfully 0` every time @RubioRic

Comment: Yes, I have already understood your question. No record will be updated if you don´t set an id.

Comment: how to i set id ?? @RubioRic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170542/discussion-between-mohammad-ali-and-rubioric).

Comment: You are editing an existing company. You already have that attribute. How do you recover the company name to show it and allow the edition? Just the same. I'm not familiar with Android but maybe you can use a hidden field (like the ones used in HTML forms) or pass somehow the id between Activities.

Comment: using putextra pass the data but how to pass the id i don't know   @RubioRic

Comment: you can not give id there for update to perform.

Comment: where to bug in my code or which code i miss ?? @AndroidTeam

Comment: when you passing company object into update method but that object do not set any id there for not update your record.

Comment: where are you setting the Id : you do like this company.setId(System.currentTimeMillis())  ; In the model class make the Id as a long

Comment: this is not work for me @AmitRanjan

Comment: Include the id value just the same as you do with the other fields (name, website, ...). Somehow you have recovered these fields values to show them. You have to recover the id before executing the update. Something like this: `company.setId(getIntent().getExtras().getString("id"));`

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me a idea, i'll change some code and it's work now again **Thank You** @RubioRic

Answer (score 0):

Code added..

```
Company company = new Company();   
company.setId(1);                            
company.setName(etCompanyName.getText().toString().trim()) 
...
long isUpdated = myDb.updateCompany(company);
```

Comment: no when you set different id and different data it update.

Comment: every time i wan to change like `company.setId(1);` , `company.setId(2);` , like show on........

Comment: no , suppose you display data remove recycler view and user select any item it display details view that time you get id that id set to company and update it.

Comment: ohhk i'll just try this my was run in my let see it's work for me or not

Comment: but hear is 1 problem i'ts iffect another record

Comment: if your id is unique in table then it not effect to another record.

Comment: id was unique if i update 1st record it's work but if i update 2nd record it's change the all record same as 2nd record

Comment: because all other data are same in company object.

Comment: there from both record same data.

Comment: so what can i do for this

Comment: That time you need to show details of particular one record into other activity and show all record into editttext box when user press update button then get all data into company object and pass update method.

Comment: how can i perform this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170580/discussion-between-mohammad-ali-and-android-team).

Comment: can you please help me for this solution ?