# Android Studio sqlite db doesnt update a specific variable in table with query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

The main goal of my program is select a station name and click the button.After click the button I am trying to increase the passenger value.
I can get the value of passengers correctly but when I am trying to update it it doesn't update the value.I tried every possible solution and couldn't fix it.What should I do or am i doing wrong something?

Here is my DB helper class

```
public class DB_Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
create_station parameter_helper;
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
public static final String DBNAME="users.db";
public DB_Helper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table users(username TEXT primary key,password TEXT,admin TEXT)");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table station(station_name TEXT primary key,latitude TEXT,longitude TEXT,passengers INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop table if exists users");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop table if exists station");
}
public Boolean insertData(String username,String password,String admin){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put("username",username);
    values.put("password",password);
    values.put("admin",admin);

    long result=db.insert("users",null,values);
    if (result==-1)
        return  false;
    else
        return true;

}
public Boolean insert_station_Data(String station_name,String latitude,String longitude,int num_passenger){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

    values.put("station_name",station_name);
    values.put("latitude",latitude);
    values.put("longitude",longitude);
    values.put("passengers",num_passenger);
    long result=db.insert("station",null,values);
    if (result==-1)
        return  false;
    else
        return true;
}
public ArrayList<String> get_Latitude(){
    ArrayList<String> station_Latitude = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select latitude from station ",null);


    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String data=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("latitude"));
        station_Latitude.add(data);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return station_Latitude;
}
public ArrayList<String> get_Longitude(){
    ArrayList<String> station_Longitude = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select longitude from station ",null);


    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String data=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("longitude"));
        station_Longitude.add(data);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return station_Longitude;
}

public ArrayList<String> get_Station_Name(){
    ArrayList<String> station_name = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select station_name from station ORDER BY rowid",null);


    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String data=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("station_name"));
        station_name.add(data);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return station_name;
}
public void user_add_passenger(String inbound_station){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteDatabase db2=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    int num_of_passenger=0;
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select passengers from station where station_name=?",new String[]{inbound_station});

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        num_of_passenger=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("passengers"));
        System.out.println("Giriyoor");
    }
    num_of_passenger+=1;
    values.put("station_name",String.valueOf(num_of_passenger));
    System.out.println("Passenger_str="+num_of_passenger);


    System.out.println(db2.update("station", values, "passengers = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(num_of_passenger)}));


}







public Boolean checkusername(String username){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from users where username=?",new String[]{username});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public Boolean checkusernamepassword(String username,String password,String admin){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from users where username=? and password=? and admin=?",new String[]{username,password,admin});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

The function which doesn't upgrade the variable:
I am trying do query firstly for getting passenger value.After that I am trying to increase the num of passenger value and updating passenger.There is no error but it doesn't update it.Even I look similar problem here [SQLiteDatabase update not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532859/sqlitedatabase-update-not-working)
I still couldn't fix the problem.

```
public void user_add_passenger(String inbound_station){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteDatabase db2=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    int num_of_passenger=0;
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select passengers from station where station_name=?",new String[]{inbound_station});

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        num_of_passenger=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("passengers"));
        System.out.println("Giriyoor");
    }
    num_of_passenger+=1;
    values.put("station_name",String.valueOf(num_of_passenger));
    System.out.println("Passenger_str="+num_of_passenger);


    System.out.println(db2.update("station", values, "passengers = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(num_of_passenger)}));


}
```

Comment: Would recommend you to start working with Room Database. It is much easier to implement and work with

Comment: We already created our tables and queries so recreating db can take so much time.But fpr next project I can give a chance to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check you are passing right column name and value inside ContentValue.

```
 values.put("station_name",String.valueOf(num_of_passenger));
```

I think it should be;

```
values.put("passengers",String.valueOf(num_of_passenger));
```

and `update query` should be like;

```
db2.update("station", values, "station_name=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(inbound_station)});
```

Comment: Me and my friend also found another solution before this.Anyways thank you so much it works too.
I wanna share it on here also 
db2.execSQL("UPDATE station SET passengers=? WHERE station_name=? ",new String[]{String.valueOf(num_of_passenger),inbound_station});

Comment: glad that you got a solution. "db2.update" is a default function. no need to pass full query like a "UPDATE tbl ..."